# node.js + json formatting

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my node app i have an object array, i have to construct another array based on this object array.

Consider my object array as:

```
{ Maximum:
   [ { xxxx: 1,
       yyyy: 6.52,
       zzzz: 1154982,
       aaaa: 1,
       bbbb: 13.55,
       cccc: 4646732,
       dddd: 3776276 } ],
  Minimum:
   [ { xxxx: 0,
       yyyy: -6.65,
       zzzz: 1,
       aaaa: 0,
       bbbb: -15.01,
       cccc: 1,
       dddd: 0 } ] }
```

My result should be like this:

```
level2:{
   keys:{
     xxxx:{max:1,
           min:0},
     yyyy:{max:6.62,
           min:-6.65},
     .....
  }
}
```

OR THIS FORMAT:

```
level2:{
       keys:{
         {     key:xxxx,
               max:1,
               min:0},
         {     key:yyyy
               max:6.62,
               min:-6.65},
         .....
      }
}
```

EDIT:

```
{
    "keys": {
        "xxx": {
            "max": 1,
            "min": 0
        },
        "yyyy": {
            "max": 6.52,
            "min": -6.65
        },
        "zzzz": {
            "max": 1154982,
            "min": 1
        },
        "aaaa": {
            "max": 1,
            "min": 0
        },
        "bbbb": {
            "max": 13.55,
            "min": -15.01
        },
        "cccc": {
            "max": 4646732,
            "min": 1
        },
        "dddd": {
            "max": 3776276,
            "min": 0
        }
    }
}
```

but i need:

```
    "356"{
    "level2":{
        "keys": {
            "xxx": {
                "max": 1,
                "min": 0
            },
            "yyyy": {
                "max": 6.52,
                "min": -6.65
            },
            "zzzz": {
                "max": 1154982,
                "min": 1
            },
            "aaaa": {
                "max": 1,
                "min": 0
            },
            "bbbb": {
                "max": 13.55,
                "min": -15.01
            },
            "cccc": {
                "max": 4646732,
                "min": 1
            },
            "dddd": {
                "max": 3776276,
                "min": 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My ultimate aim to combine max and min value.Help to solve this.Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var json = { Maximum:
   [ { xxxx: 1,
       yyyy: 6.52,
       zzzz: 1154982,
       aaaa: 1,
       bbbb: 13.55,
       cccc: 4646732,
       dddd: 3776276 } ],
  Minimum:
   [ { xxxx: 0,
       yyyy: -6.65,
       zzzz: 1,
       aaaa: 0,
       bbbb: -15.01,
       cccc: 1,
       dddd: 0 } ] }
;
level2 = {keys:{}};

for (i in json.Maximum[0]) {
    console.log(json.Maximum[0][i], i); 
    level2.keys[i] = {
        max: json.Maximum[0][i], 
        min: json.Minimum[0][i]
    };
}
```

Comment: +1 for your valuable time..

Comment: I'm sorry, I can not understand what is wrong with the answer I posted.

Comment: just nest it inside another object console.log({"356":level2,})

Comment: that 356 is dynamic...How can i assign it dynamically.. i tried it..i can't acheive it..can u please modify the code..

Comment: r u there??????????????

Comment: var someobject = {};
someobject[my_dynamic_number] = level2;

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50668/discussion-between-thorsummoner-and-subburaj)